# Do I need to seal the concrete tub when building a swimming pool?

Tags: waterproofing, pool, tiling

We are building our own house with a small indoor concrete pool. [These are the tiles](https://www.wallsandfloors.co.uk/catalogsearch/result/?q=Tidal) we will be finishing the inside of the pool with.

How and with what do we need to waterproof the concrete with before applying tiles? There is so much contradictory info out there as to what and if anything is needed.

Advice much appreciated.

Comment: One word: plaster

Comment: I'm afraid one word doesn't help me understand your suggestion, @Tyson. Does a coating of plaster change things somehow? I always assumed that it was every bit as porous as raw concrete.

Comment: @isherwood plaster, at least pool plaster—I don’t know if there are different types of plaster, is made of fine silica and marble dust and hardens virtually impervious to water.

Comment: @Lesley an indoor pool is something that at first seems like a good idea, but issues do arise with them and can be a major headache. Some things to consider is the chemicals to treat the pool - indoors .just an FYI .if you plan to sell it one day . a house here with an indoor pool has been for sale for 4 years - it was completely updated quite nicely - and still not sold, the indoor pool is the sales stopper.